# How to prevent combination of different alias type in c++?

Tags: c++, compilation, g++, warnings, alias

Is there any way to prevent mixing two different alias type that actually refer to the same underlying type in c++ ?

For instance, I would like to get a compilation warning with `g++` for the following (although valid) program:

```
using TypeA = float;
using TypeB = float;

void foo(TypeA a) {}

int main()
{
    TypeB b;
    foo(b); // valid but how to get a warning?

    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately neither of `-Wall`, `-Wextra` or `-pedantic` warn on this.

I'm looking for a solution that works with alias type (where I don't have to create two classes `TypeA` and `TypeB`).

Comment: boost has a typesafe typedef called `BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF`, just in case this is what you are looking for

Comment: I'm not currently using boost but this [BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/boost/strong_typedef.hpp) is indeed a nice solution, thank you. The ideal would be a **g++ compilation option** to enable this kind of warnings, but I'm not sure such option exists...

Comment: I find the more important warning here that you're using an uninitialized variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it shouldn't be possible. Aliases are intended to not be a types, but an "aliases", synonyms. This means that they are intended to **not be distingushable** from the type they're aliasing. Type aliases don't have their own identity.

Mentioned in comments BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF in fact creates new type, which can be than distinguished from other types during function overloading etc. by compiler.

Read more:

- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias#Explanation
- http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.typedef
- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/boost/serialization/strong_typedef.hpp